# Is calling persist() flush() and refresh() in one method to persist an entity the right way?

Tags: jpa, persistence

My intention is to return a newly persisted entity just in the same business call to a client in order to get the generated primary key needed for further business logic. Calling a finder method to find the entity by name or some known attributes again would cause a second server roundtrip I would like to avoid (time is money ;-). So I created the following method:

```
public Entity persist(Entity entity) {
    em.persist(entity);
    em.flush();
    em.refresh(entity);
    // now the entity has an id
    return entity;
}
```

But now I'm wondering whether this is the right way to do this. It feels "strange" somehow. The JPA specification is quite clear about this: the EntityManager's persist() method returns void - sounds like "fire and forget" for me. But my client is dependent on the primary key. Is there an alternative solution to my method above? Is this best practice in my case? What do you think?

Comment: Additional reading:  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1440

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no single "right way" ... otherwise that would be the API. You call the methods appropriate for your application, and the use-case of that method. If you need the object in the datastore immediately after, then you call flush(), otherwise you don't. If you have other processes that can update things then you call refresh() otherwise you don't. And so on.

Answer (score 4):

The entity passed to `persist` is made persistent. That means that, now or later in the transaction, it will be written to database and an ID will be generated for this entity. The instance itself (the one you passed to `persist`) will have the generated ID assigned to it. So, just persisting the entity is, most of the time, sufficient, since when the client will call `getId()`, the transaction where `persist` has been called has been committed already, which means that the entity has an ID.

Comment: Just persisting the entity is not sufficient in my case. Calling getId() after persisting will return null. This is not what I want.

Comment: Calling getId() after persisting will return null, *unless the transaction has committed*. So, if it's the client who calls getId(), there's no problem.

Comment: Well maybe I should have mentioned that the client is a Eclipse rich client. If the client calls getId() there is no communication taking place with the server part so the client has no access to the ID in this case without calling a finder business method reloading the entity which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: You missed my point. If you call persist, in a transaction, and call getId() just after, in the same transaction, you won't have any ID. But as soon as the transaction commits, of you call getId() on the same object, it will return an ID because the ID is assigned at flush time (and a flush occurs at commit time). So, if you return your entity from a remote call, the client will find the ID in the returned entity because the EM will assign the ID at flush time, and then the entity will be serialized to your client.

Answer (score 1):

If using eclipselink, you should try the

```
@ReturnInsert
```

annotation. You set it with the @Id and you are telling Eclipselink to get the ID from the DB.

Comment: can u please elaborate ur answer with example as well

Answer (score 1):

If you need the id within the same transaction, then yes, you will need to `flush` or otherwise commit the transaction, and you will probably need to `refresh` the entity as well.